# ph_slidelink - not sure how to use it?

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

it is great that officer has a function to create links to slides internal to the presentation. However I don't know how to use it from the examples available. I never see an actual hyperlink to a page appearing in the example below e.g.:

```
fileout <- tempfile(fileext = ".pptx")
doc <- read_pptx()
doc <- add_slide(doc, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
doc <- ph_with_text(x = doc, type = "title", str = "Un titre 1")
doc <- add_slide(doc, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
doc <- ph_with_text(x = doc, type = "title", str = "Un titre 2")
doc <- on_slide(doc, 1)
slide_summary(doc) # read column id here
doc <- ph_slidelink(x = doc, id_chr = "2", slide_index = 2)

print(doc, target = fileout )
```

Here I don't see any link for page 2 appearing anywhere...
Can you help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on "Un titre 1" (with view mode, not edit mode), slide 2 is displayed.

`ph_slidelink(x = doc, id_chr = "2", slide_index = 2)`: when clicking on shape with id "2", display slide 2 (slide_index = 2)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks David!

I understand, but I wanted to have text linking to another slide. Meanwhile I figured out how to do it in this fork:
https://github.com/danielinteractive/officer
in the function ph_add_text2. Feel free to pull something of this into your package, probably others need this too!

Cheers
Daniel